# Execute a function by a component with Angular 5

Tags: angular

I would like to create an "action" component that is supposed to act link a "a" element. However, I want to be able to know when the function executed when clicking on the component is finished. Basically, the goal is to display a message while the action is executed.

I just made this simple component:

```
export class ActionComponent {

    @Input()
    public loadingLabel: string;

    @Input()
    public promise: () => Promise<void>;

    public running: boolean = false;

    public run(): void {
        this.running = true;

        this.promise().then(() => this.running = false);
    }
}
```

That I call this way:

```
<action [promise]="accept" [loadingLabel]="'Accepting'">Confirm</action>
```

It works well with simple callback functions (so in this example `accept`). However, when the function is a bit more complex, for example, using an injected Angular service, it does not work.

In this example, the accept function looks like this:

```
public async accept(): Promise<void> {
    this._modalService.showModal({
        ...
    });
}
```

Where `_modalService` is injected in the component. When I execute this, the console says that `this._modalService` is null or undefined.

The need is pretty simple but I can't figure out a way to achieve it.

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a component that displays a link. When you click on the link, a loading spinner should appear with a message until the function executed is completed. The idea is that the function is calling a web service, so I want to show a loading indicator during the execution and I don't want to implement this logic for every link of that type.

Comment: is there any reason you're binding the service via an @Input? Services are supposed to be injected via DI into the constructor.

Comment: What are you talking about ? No service are passed via Input. promise is just a function that returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a loading animation by installing ngx-loading into your project, and in app.module.ts file import { LoadingModule } from 'ngx-loading' and in imports array add LoadingModule.

Then within the html of your component with the link that is performing the action, put this html:

```
<ngx-loading [show]="loadingStuff"></ngx-loading>
```

And in your TypeScript file before you call the web service set `loadingStuff = true;`

and subscribe to the call and when it returns set `loadingStuff = false;`

at the top of your component's class you would want to declare your variable as false: `loadingStuff = false;`

....

```
linkClicked() {
    this.loadingStuff = true;
    myService.getSomethingFromDatabase().subscribe(data => {
      //do something with your data
       this.loadingStuff = false;
     })
}
```